# How to convert ImageVector to ImagePainter in JetpackCompose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

In JetpackCompose Image, we can have either an `ImageBitmap`, `ImageVector` or `ImagePainter`. In `ImagePainter`, we have more control over the image to be drawn.

So we can easily convert `ImageBitmap` to `ImagePicture` using

```
val imagePicture = ImagePainter(imageBitmap)
```

But how can I convert `ImageVector` to `ImagePicture`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like I should change from `ImageVector` to `VectorPicture` instead since both `VectorPicture` and `ImagePicture` are of `Picture type. I can use` rememberVectorPainter` function.

```
val imageVector = rememberVectorPainter(imageVector)
```

Comment: Some explanation in https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/loading-image-in-android-jetpack-compose-made-easy-8cb593b26260